# Latex Citation in matplotlib Legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am generating figures for a technical paper using Python with matplotlib. Is there a way to include a Latex/Bibtex citation in the legend text? Ideally I would like a solution something like the following but haven't found anything that works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0., 1., num=100)
y = x**2

plt.plot(x, y, label=r'Data \cite{<key>}')
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You would have to manually input the citation, so why not just label it `'Data Ref. [#]'`?

Comment: us psfrag https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSfrag

Comment: I am using this in my thesis and the citation numbers change frequently and constantly updating the figures becomes a hassle.

Comment: Oh, you want to automate the process up updating the figures. Gotcha.

Comment: I suspect that you will have to write a custom version of the `texmanager.py` See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/texmanager.py

Comment: A custom latex preamble that includes the bib file is another option (if you specify `text.usetex=True` in rc params or use the PGF backend, you can use a custom latex preamble).  No idea if that will work, but it might be worth a shot. If you take that route, you might want to go with the PGF backend for your plots.  I can't test it at the moment, but have a look here: http://matplotlib.org/users/pgf.html and here: http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html

Comment: @tcaswell I checked out psfrag and it would have been great. Unfortunately it seems that the newer version of matplotlib breaks this functionality due to the handling of text.

Comment: just for the sake of completeness, [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.matplotlib.general/26740/) is an explanation why `psfrag` and `matplotlib` don't get along.

Comment: @JoeKington Thank you for the advice of using matplotlib with pgf. You lead me to the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done using the matplotlib pgf backend for python. The python file for generating the graph is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('pgf')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0., 1., num=100)
y = x**2

plt.plot(x, y, label=r'Data \cite{<key>}')
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.savefig('fig.pgf')
```

The pgf file can then be utilized in a latex paper as such:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \input{fig.pgf}
    \caption{Test Figure}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Whenever the latex file is compiled, the citation in the legend will be updated automatically.

Comment: Nice! Good to know it works! I think I'll have to use that trick in the future...

Answer (score 2):

Check out [tikzplotlib](https://github.com/nschloe/tikzplotlib) (a project of mine). You can use it to save matplotlib figures as TikZ/Pgfplots which retains a lot of informations and which are very easily editable. Adding a BibTeX citation as a legend is no problem at all.

Comment: Importing plots onto Latex from matplotlib is a joy when using this module! Thanks for your contribution.